# How can I give alternative names to functions?

Tags: c++, function, alias

Let's say I have a function called `get_color`:

```cpp
std::string get_color()
{
    return "green";
}
```

I also want to have the same function but with the en-gb spelling, which is `get_colour`. I could just make an identical function and call the get_color function like this:

```cpp
std::string get_colour()
{
    return get_color()
}
```

but this can get very tricky to maintain. Is there any other way to give a second name to a function?

Comment: Do any of these ideas work for you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582666/providing-a-function-alias-in-gcc

Comment: @JohnZwinck those seem to be MSVC-specific and more about mangling than aliases.

Comment: See here. That should works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178028/giving-a-function-implementation-more-than-one-name-in-c

Comment: @t.niese nice find; voting to close as dupe

Comment: So you would use either use perfect forwarding or you could use `constexpr auto get_colour = get_color;`

Comment: why is it tricky to maintain?

Comment: @idclev463035818 whenever you want to change the function parameters, you will have to change the first function and the second

Comment: @Bathsheba why overthinking. `constexpr auto alternative = alternitive;` or `constexpr auto alternative(alternitive);` and your `auto alternative(alternitive);` are not that far off, except that the for `constexpr` version tje compiler will directly call `alternitive`, because `alternative` can't change. Not sure why you removed the duplicate?

Comment: @t.niese. Never mind about the duplicate find, what's done is done. However, you ought to put your answer-disguised-as-a-comment as an answer, as it's better than mine.

Comment: @Bathsheba I wrote it only as an additional comment just to hint to the correct answer, because I already linked to the duplicate that shows `constexpr auto get_colour = get_color;` as solution.

Comment: This is a bad idea. It makes code much harder to read, since two apparently different things are actually the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
auto get_colour(get_color);
```

is one way. Needs a little more thought if you want to support overloaded functions.

Answer (score 3):

A C-style macro would work, but I'm not a fan of macros.

`#define get_colour(x) get_color(x)`

Comment: Should probably use `__VA_ARGS__`.

Answer (score 2):

I only write it here as an answer because I can't mark it as a duplicate to [C++11: How to alias a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864125/c11-how-to-alias-a-function) or [How do I assign an alias to a function name in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053561/how-do-i-assign-an-alias-to-a-function-name-in-c) again.

Making an alias can be done using:

```
constexpr auto get_colour = get_color;
// or
constexpr auto get_colour(get_color);
```

```
const auto get_colour = get_color;
// or
const auto get_colour(get_color);
```

The advantage over:

```
auto get_colour = get_color;
// OR
auto get_colour(get_color);
```

is that the compiler will know for the `constexpr`/`const` version that `get_colour` won't change, so it can directly map the `get_colour` call to `get_color`. For the none `constexpr` version you will have an indirection over the stored pointer.

If you have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string get_color()
{
    return "green";
}

auto get_colour = get_color;

int main() {
  std::cout << get_colour() << "\n";
}
```

You can see that at the `[QWORD PTR get_colour[abi:cxx11][rip]]` that the is not inlined, because `get_colour` could changed:

```
get_color[abi:cxx11]():
        lea     rdx, [rdi+16]
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi+20], 110
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], rdx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi+16], 1701147239
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+8], 5
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi+21], 0
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "\n"
main:
        push    rbp
        sub     rsp, 32
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    [QWORD PTR get_colour[abi:cxx11][rip]]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]
        mov     rsi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        mov     rdi, rax
        mov     edx, 1
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        lea     rax, [rsp+16]
        cmp     rdi, rax
        je      .L8
        call    operator delete(void*)
```

But for the `constexpr` version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string get_color()
{
    return "green";
}

constexpr auto get_colour = get_color;

int main() {
  std::cout << get_colour() << "\n";
}
```

The function call to `get_colour` can be inlined (`get_color[abi:cxx11]()` is not called) but the generated code directly appears in `main:`:

```
get_color[abi:cxx11]():
        lea     rdx, [rdi+16]
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi+20], 110
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], rdx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi+16], 1701147239
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+8], 5
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi+21], 0
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "\n"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     edx, 5
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 40
        lea     rbx, [rsp+16]
        mov     BYTE PTR [rsp+20], 110
        mov     rsi, rbx
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rbx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+16], 1701147239
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], 5
        mov     BYTE PTR [rsp+21], 0
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        mov     rdi, rax
        mov     edx, 1
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        cmp     rdi, rbx
        je      .L8
        call    operator delete(void*)
```

Or use perfect forwarding which will work for both free and member functions:

```
void get_color() {
}

template <typename... Args>
auto get_colour(Args&&... args) {
  return get_color(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

For c++11  `-> decltype(get_color(std::forward<Args>(args)...))` needs to be added:

```
template <typename... Args>
auto get_colour(Args&&... args) -> decltype(get_color(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
  return get_color(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: @caelras there the only way is IMHO perfect forwarding [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9864472).

Answer (score 0):

In cpp11 you can use the functional standard library, this fulfils your requirement

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

    std::string func()
    {
    return "hello";
    }
    
    int main()
    {
    std::function<std::string()> newfunc = func;
    
    std::cout << newfunc() << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
    }
```

For more info have a look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: That does not really create an alias, and is bad for regarding optimization. But most importantly if fails the requirement of the OP: `but this can get very tricky to maintain. Is there any other way to give a second name to a function?` and `whenever you want to change the function parameters, you will have to change the first function and the second` in case the signature of `func` changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use reference variable.

```
std::string get_color(){
    return "green";
}

auto & get_colour = get_color;
```

Answer (score 0):

This what I ended up doing:

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
auto get_colour(Args&&... args)
{
  return get_color(static_cast<Args>(args)...);
}
```

**Note**: This only works with C++ 14 or higher