# How to assign alias to template function in C++?

Tags: c++, function, templates, alias

I am writing a few mathematical functions for C++ and have just learned to use template functions so I don't have to make loads of overloaded copies of a simple function for all the different types.
I have made a test program that has all the different types I'm likely to use and runs each one through the function to check they all work ok.

What I want to do now is assign an alias to one of my template functions to call it with a different name, so I can write new functions and run them through the test by changing the alias to be the new function rather than going through the whole code with find and replace to change to the new function I want to test.

I have tried [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/162360/)

```
template <typename T> using B = A<T>;
```

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053561/how-do-i-assign-an-alias-to-a-function-name-in-c)

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto alias_to_old = old_function<T>;
```

but they both throw errors.

Please note I am pretty much a beginner at C++ so don't use jargon in your answers, and clear examples would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: "they both throw errors". May we know what those are?

Comment: Probably just not passing the right compiler flags for C++11/14

Comment: You could also write wrapper.

Comment: Are you wanting something akin to a `typedef`?  .. e.g. `typdef A<T> B;` then you could just use `B b` where `b` is of type `A<T>` ??