# Emulate Import as functionality from python in C++

Tags: c++

In python I can do:
`from long_and_painful import still_way_to_long as short`

In C++ I am stuck with:

```
using long::and::painful::stillWayToLong;
... //Code and Stuff
stillWayToLong("Why must I type this so often?");
```

Am I missing something that would make this more pythonic?

Comment: _"make this more pythonic"_, no. But you can perhaps not use very long identifiers.

Comment: Well, definitely don't try to use `short` as an identifier in C++. Or `long`, or `and`.

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053561/how-do-i-assign-an-alias-to-a-function-name-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
auto x = long::and::painful::stillWayToLong;  // If this is an object/function
x("Why must I type this so often?");


using X = typename long::and::painful::stillWayToLong; // If this is a type.
X bob;
```

Comment: And for the sake of completeness `using x = long::and::painful::stillWayToLong;` if `stillWayTooLong` is a namespace.