# Way to simplify static member function calling?

Tags: c++

**MyCode:**

```
#include "YourClass.h"

class MyClass
{
public:
    void doThis()
    {
        YourClass::doThis();
    }
    void doThat()
    {
        YourClass::doThat();
    }
    void doSomething()
    {
        YourClass::doSomething();
    }
};
```

Is it possible to simplify the static member function calling so I don't have to re-write `YourClass::` whenever I call its static members?

Or is it a better practice to leave it like it is?

Comment: You mean, inside other static member functions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053561/how-do-i-assign-an-alias-to-a-function-name-in-c

Comment: With that being said, there's no reason to do this. Writing `YourClass::` is completely fine. In fact, I'd say that if you don't, it can make the code more confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

```
auto doThis =  bind(YourClass::doThis);
```

Thanks to @p.picard You can also do it without bind:

```
auto doThis =  YourClass::doThis;
```

[compile](https://godbolt.org/z/bcQV2e)