# Can you define synonyms in C++?

Tags: c++

I have this problem: A class of mine has a function called f. Some member function needs to call a global function called f. Now that's impossible, as I understand. To reach the global function from the class I need to call it under another name. How can I assign another name to it?

Do synonyms exist in C++ ? To define a preprocessor symbol doesn't work here: The names must be different AFTER preprocessing. So I have this global function:

```
double f(double x)
{
    return x;
}
```

I could of course write another copy of the function with another name:

```
double f_(double x)
{
    return x;
}
```

but that's ugly. An elegant solution, please. I'm thinking about defining a global function pointer:

```
double (*f_)(double x) = &f;
```

or an inline wrapper function:

```
inline double f_(double x)
{
    return f(x);
}
```

But these are not truly synonyms. Is there a nicer way?

Comment: Use `::f` (global scope).

Comment: @iz_ You were first with this and deserves the cred that somebody else got.

Comment: It's okay, I'm not here for the reputation anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have this problem: A class of mine has a function called f. Some member function needs to call a global function called f. Now that's impossible, as I understand.

It's not impossible. Simply use the fully qualified name `::f` to refer to the hidden global function.

As for giving an alias for a function, there is no way for the function itself, but if you put the function in a namespace, then you can give an alias to the namespace and thereby an alias to the qualified name of the function.

Comment: Not a using statement, but: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053561/how-do-i-assign-an-alias-to-a-function-name-in-c

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed :).

Comment: @NathanOliver That's a useful thread. Strange that eerorika's answer doesn't appear in there.