# Define already declared function as an alias to another

Tags: c++, arduino

In my Arduino program, I have a set of different options for `setup`/`loop` functions that I'm planning to select using a `#define` macro. I have the following already:

```cpp
namespace Part2 {
void setup() {
    // ...
}
void loop() {
    // ...
}
}  // namespace Part2

// ...

// Choose which tutorial video will be built
#define PREFIX Part2

void setup() { PREFIX::setup(); }

void loop() { PREFIX::loop(); }
```

However, I think this looks quite messy and I'm wondering if there's a way to define `setup`/`loop` as an alias to `PREFIX::setup`/`PREFIX::loop` instead of using this one-line function call. I've tried most of the methods suggested in these two SO posts ([Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864125/c11-how-to-alias-a-function), [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053561/how-do-i-assign-an-alias-to-a-function-name-in-c)), but both result in variants of the same compiler error:

```
src/main.cpp:27:15: error: 'void (* setup)()' redeclared as different kind of symbol
```

I think this is because the `Arduino.h` header file included in every program has already declared `setup`/`loop` and the syntaxes mentioned in the aforementioned SO posts deal with declaring/defining an entirely new function alias (*as opposed to defining an already declared function as an alias to another*). Is there an easy way to make this work?

Comment: when the function is declared in a different namespace there should be no clash, ie no error for redefinition. Please include a [mcve]

Comment: Why not put the common parts in a library and create a clean project for each tutorial that uses that library?

Comment: I don't quite understand. As far as I know, this is a minimal reproducible example for this question. I have multiple different "sub-programs" in separate namespaces that I want to be able to switch between using this `PREFIX` macro. As far as I can tell, I have refactored all of the common parts out. Could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: Would you like to see some of the example "sub-programs"? I can link to my repo on GitHub if you'd like...

Comment: minimal reproducible example means enough code so others can reproduce the same issue, but not more. When I copy the code you posted and try to compile it this is what happens: https://godbolt.org/z/ahhfvMfhe

Comment: Okay, I understand. Sorry, I thought that what I had already said describes the program structure I have. I've edited my OP to include some of the `Part2` namespace.

Comment: For the record, this is the Arduino project I'm referring to: https://github.com/neilbalch/ESP32-FreeRTOS-Tutorial