# Renaming/re-declaring functions for CFFI?

Tags: python, namespaces, function-declaration, python-cffi

I have a C library for which I'm trying to create (out-of-line, API mode) [CFFI](https://github.com/python-cffi/cffi) bindings. The C library provides various implementations of each function, but all of them have this giant, obnoxious prefix added onto them.

For example, the AVX-optimized implementation of the *foo* function from the *GreenSpam* submodule is named `THELIBRARY_GREENSPAM_OPTIMIZED_AVX_foo()`; I'll be exposing this as `TheLibrary.Spam.GreenSpam.foo`, with CPU optimizations chosen *transparently* at `import`-time.

I *am* capable of determining this prefix for each module at `ffibuilder.compile()`-time, so I'd like to try to lean into [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) to the highest degree possible. My code currently looks like this, which as you can see is about as horrible as it gets as regards DRY **and** doesn't provide any easy or obvious avenue for moving forward at the run-time algorithm choice:

```py
# TheLibrary/Spam/GreenSpam.py
from . import _greenspam_generic
from . import _greenspam_optimized_avx  # TODO

__all__ = ['foo', 'oof']

def foo(bar):
    """GreenSpam foo"""
    _out = _greenspam_generic.ffi.new(f"uint8_t[{len(bar):d}]")
    _greenspam_generic.lib.THELIBRARY_GREENSPAM_GENERIC_foo(bar, len(bar), _out)
    # void function never errors
    return bytes(_out)

def oof(baz):
    """GreenSpam oof"""
    _out = _greenspam_generic.ffi.new(f"uint8_t[{len(baz):d}]")
    err = _greenspam_generic.lib.THELIBRARY_GREENSPAM_GENERIC_oof(baz, len(baz), _out)
    if err:
        raise RuntimeError("oof")
    return bytes(_out)
```

```py
# TheLibrary/Spam/PurpleSpam.py
from . import _purplespam_generic
from . import _purplespam_optimized_avx  # TODO

__all__ = ['foo', 'oof']

def foo(bar):
    """PurpleSpam foo"""
    _out = _purplespam_generic.ffi.new(f"uint8_t[{len(bar):d}]")
    _purplespam_generic.lib.THELIBRARY_PURPLESPAM_GENERIC_foo(bar, len(bar), _out)
    # void function never errors
    return bytes(_out)

def oof(baz):
    """PurpleSpam oof"""
    _out = _purplespam_generic.ffi.new(f"uint8_t[{len(baz):d}]")
    err = _purplespam_generic.lib.THELIBRARY_PURPLESPAM_GENERIC_oof(baz, len(baz), _out)
    if err:
        raise RuntimeError("oof")
    return bytes(_out)
```

I would really like to flatten out these C library function names when I'm running `ffi.compile()`, ideally exposing aliases something like `(fr'\b{re.escape(prefix)}_(\w+)\b', r'\1')` to make my *bindings'* code cleaner and better, and in particular to enable me to add in those import-time CPU choices without having to multiplicatively duplicate my code *again*.

I'd like to track the upstream library as closely as possible, so doing transformations on the C source to remove these prefixes would be painful and I'd like to ask in particular about *alternatives* to doing that.

However, I would be fine to add, for example during `ffibuilder.set_source()`, normalized **aliases** to the mangled names, especially if that could be done in a DRY-focused way. (I did try [function references](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3053561/1874170), but apparently those are C++ only?)

---

The specific library I'm currently looking at is [PQClean](https://github.com/PQClean/PQClean), but I expect I'll run up against this in future bindings as well, so that's another point against drilling down into transforming the C source too much, because I'll have to re-duplicate that effort each time I run across a new library, and possibly again each time that library refactors their header spaghetti.

Comment: This \*is\* a duplicate of [#77275165 "Transform C function names in Python CFFI"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77275165/transform-c-function-names-in-python-cffi), which was eerily asked just an hour before I had the same question, but was deleted *by the author* immediately after posting with no reason publicly given... (\*admittedly, I'm not sure if SE *allows* you to attach a reason when deleting a question, but my confusion remains either way)

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly play some Python-level tricks.  I would do something like... (admittedly, this uses quite a bit of various Python hacks)

```
# to make the builds "mylib_<suffix>.so"
for suffix in ['generic', 'optimized_avx']:
    builder = FFIBuilder()
    builder.set_source("mylib_" + suffix,
    f"""
        #include <mylib.h>
        int foo_{suffix}(int x, int y);
        void bar_{suffix}(void);
    """)
    builder.compile()

# minimal source code for mylib_generic.py
import _mylib_maker
globals().update(_mylib_maker.make("generic"))

# minimal source code for mylib_optimized_avx.py
import _mylib_maker
globals().update(_mylib_maker.make("optimized_avx"))

# actual Python-side wrappers defined in _mylib_maker.py
def make(suffix):
    mod = __import__("mylib_" + suffix)
    c_foo = getattr(mod, "foo_" + suffix)
    c_bar = getattr(mod, "bar_" + suffix)

    my_funcs = []

    @my_funcs.append
    def foo(x, y):
        result = c_foo(x, y)
        if result < 0: raise Exception
        return result

    @my_funcs.append
    def bar():
        return c_bar()

    return {func.__name__: func for func in my_funcs}
```